# How I can download issues from Bitbucket repository to WebStorm?

Tags: ubuntu, bitbucket, webstorm, issue-tracking

My problem is I have a repository **Bitbucket** but my issues are in another repository which made a fork.

I have not seen how to download these issues with my **WebStorm**.

I try setting **WebStorm** tasks: **Task -> Tasks & Contexts -> Configure Servers**; but I not resolved.

If that can not be I may have found a client from which you can download these issues?

I work on **Ubuntu 15.10**.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I found the solution, the problem is that the plugins using WebStorm for connection with problems in a repository Bitbucket this apparently quite some time not support it.

Dmitry Cherkas made a fork the repository and solved this problem, here I leave the steps with which I resolved:

1- Download the plugins from https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads (try to select the latest version)

2- Go in WebStorm configuration: Settings -> Plugins -> Install plugin from disk.

3- Restart WebStorm.

4- Go on the WebStorm to: Tools -> Tasks & Contents -> Configure Severs -> + (Add and select Bitbucket)

I hope you learn.